# jQuery plugin for timeout user and display lightbox alert warning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking fo ra jQuery plugin that does the following behaviour:
        1. Find user inactivity for a period of 10 minutes. 
        2. After 10 minutes display an alert or lightbox message. I believe lightbox would be better.
        3. After 5 more minutes, perform an action.

```
    My javascript code is : 

            <script type="text/javascript">
    var idleTime = 0;
    var activeTime = 0;
    var warningFlag = 0;
    setInterval(function checkIdle() {
        idleTime += 1;
        activeTime += 1;
        //document.write(idleTime + ' ' + activeTime);
        if(idleTime > 5) {
            alert("Idle from last 5 seconds!! You have been active for last "+ activeTime);
            warningFlag=1;
        }
        if((idleTime > 10) && (warningFlag==1)) {
            alert("Idle from last 10 seconds!! You have been active for last "+ activeTime);
            window.location = "www.tinyprints.com";
        }
        window.onload = resetTimer;
        document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
        document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    },1000);

    function resetTimer() {
         idleTime = 0;
    }

</script>
    But i was thinking to use a jQuery plugin.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good jQuery plugin here: 
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/creating-a-mint-com-style-idle-logout-timer-using-jquery/
which allows you to do exactly what you want.  You can easily get it to change pages after 10 minutes by changing the `redirectAfter` parameter.